# actool exited eith code 1 and arch exited with code 1 Issue facing while build the app on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui

```
1)Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       actool exited with code 1
            C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\15.0.101-preview.11.551\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets    755 
    


2)Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       arch exited with code 1
                C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\15.0.101-preview.11.551\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets    755
```

how can i resolve this issue,And the following issue is same as other one ,What can i do to resolve this issue

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "appicon". C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\15.0.101-preview.11.551\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets    755
```

Comment: How do you get this error? Did you do some specific operations? Could you share the stops for us to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you change the icon to be anything other than appicon.svg under Resources > AppIcon directory.

It is misleading and confusing given the documentation states you can override with the following in the project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But this will result in the above error.  Change the new icon you are using to the same name, make sure it is under the same folder and it will work.